# Lagrangian of a piezoelectric material

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, modeling

I'm confused about the Lagrangian of a piezoelectric material. I've seen multiple sources which seem to contradict each other.
The way I personally approach the problem is the following (*$\underline{note}$: I'm ignoring the work done by external forces and charges for now, since they are not relevant to the discussion*):

$L = K - U $

where $K$ is the kinetic energy, and $U$ is the potential energy which consists of mechanical strain energy $U_m$ + electrical energy $U_e$.

$K = \int\frac{1}{2}\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i dV$

$U_m = \int\frac{1}{2}S_{i}T_{i} dV$

$U_e = \int\frac{1}{2}E_{i}D_{i} dV$

where $\rho$ is the density, $\dot u_i$ is the velocity, $S_i$ is the strain tensor (Voigt notation), $T_i$ is the stress tensor (Voigt notation), $E_i$ is the electric field, $D_i$ is the electric displacement field. This results in the Lagrangian:

$  L = \frac{1}{2}\int(\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i - S_{i}T_{i} - E_{i}D_{i}) dV$

The problem is that most references write the Lagrangian as:

$  L = \frac{1}{2}\int(\rho \dot u_i \dot u_i - S_{i}T_{i} + E_{i}D_{i}) dV$

with the sign in front of the electrical energy reversed. Examples:

[Example 1](https://scmero.ulb.ac.be/Publications/Thesis/Piefort01.pdf): if you go to page 56, you'll see they derive the Lagrangian from the electrical enthalpy, and I don't get why it gives a different result (in the form of a + sign in front of the electrical energy).

[Example 2](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=lCePDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&dq=piezoelectric%20%22lagrangian%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqwp3bzN3oAhUBxYUKHVooDGQQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=piezoelectric%20%22lagrangian%22&f=true): same result, with the constitutive relations substituted in the Lagrangian.

So my question is twofold:

(1) Where is the error in my approach in that it yields the wrong sign in front of the electrical energy?

(2) In the main book I'm studying, which is *Engineering Analysis of Smart Material Systems.* Donald J. Leo, 2007, if you go to [page 218](https://books.google.com.lb/books?id=jGAvKfLykNsC&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=The%20tilde%20over%20a%20symbol%20denotes%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20strain%20and%20electric%20displacement%20are%20expressed%20in%20terms%20of%20the%20local%20piezoelectric%20coordinates%20and%20not%20the%20global%20coordinates.%20The%20local%20coordinate%20system%20for%20each%20piezoelectric%20element%20can%20be%20transformed%20to%20the%20global%20coordinates%20through%20the%20transformations&source=bl&ots=5tyv1NmGD0&sig=ACfU3U2coUWoCyy1dRJ25BpxoEszouMnTQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQhc_02t7oAhVs8-AKHf4rAXMQ6AEwAHoECAsQKA#v=onepage&q=The%20tilde%20over%20a%20symbol%20denotes%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20strain%20and%20electric%20displacement%20are%20expressed%20in%20terms%20of%20the%20local%20piezoelectric%20coordinates%20and%20not%20the%20global%20coordinates.%20The%20local%20coordinate%20system%20for%20each%20piezoelectric%20element%20can%20be%20transformed%20to%20the%20global%20coordinates%20through%20the%20transformations&f=false), equation 5.47, the author gives the potential energy of a piezoelectric material (static case, no kinetic energy so $L=-U$):

$  U = \int(\frac{1}{2}S_{i}c_{ij}^D S_{j} - S_ih_{ij}D_j + \frac{1}{2}D_{i}\beta_{ij}^SD_{j}) dV$
which is actually derivable from *my Lagrangian approach* rather than the one given in the two previous reference examples when you substitute the constitutive relations into the Lagrangian:

$ T_i = c_{ij}^DS_j - h_{ij}D_j $

$ E_i = - h_{ji}S_j + \beta_{ij}^S D_j $

How do we reconcile the contradictory references?

Comment: How does one account for the direction of the electric field? If I apply a ten volt potential along the rod with the pos on the left, what is the strain response (h)? Now if I walk around to the other side, the positive potential is on the right, so the strain response to a minus ten volt potential must be opposite (-h). But that's nonsense. It comes down to vector fields vs [Pseudovector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector). Pseudovectors need some reference, or preferred, coordinate system. IEEE is paywalled, but they appear have designated the preferred treatment.

Comment: I don't fully understand your reasoning here. But to your point: yes, the strain response with depend on the direction of the electric field. This is because a piezoelectric material is permanently strained (elongated) and polarized during the poling process, and so applying an electric field in the poling direction increases the polarization and thus elongates the material further, while applying an electric field opposite to the poling direction decreases the polarization and thus shrinks the material. But I don't see how all that relates to my question, which is about the internal energy